# Copy file to remote computer

Tags: vb.net

I have created a program which will copy from my computer to other remote computers a specific file. I have successfully did this, but only in the driver C:\ . My question is how can I copy the file to the D:\ drive?

I have tried adding **\157.60.113.28\D:\testnew\right.bmp** but with no luck. Let me know!

```
Imports System 
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
Imports System.Security.Principal 
Imports System.Security.Permissions 
Public Class Form1 
<DllImport("advapi32.DLL", SetLastError:=True)> _ 
Public Shared Function LogonUser(ByVal lpszUsername As String, ByVal lpszDomain As String, _ 
    ByVal lpszPassword As String, ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _ 
    ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Integer 
End Function 
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    Dim admin_token As IntPtr 
    Dim wid_current As WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() 
    Dim wid_admin As WindowsIdentity = Nothing 
    Dim wic As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing 
    Try 
        MessageBox.Show("Copying file...") 
        If LogonUser("Local Admin name", "Local computer name", "pwd", 9, 0, admin_token) <> 0 Then 
            wid_admin = New WindowsIdentity(admin_token) 
            wic = wid_admin.Impersonate() 
            System.IO.File.Copy("C:\right.bmp", "\\157.60.113.28\testnew\right.bmp", True) 
            MessageBox.Show("Copy succeeded") 
        Else 
            MessageBox.Show("Copy Failed") 
        End If 
    Catch se As System.Exception 
        Dim ret As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() 
        MessageBox.Show(ret.ToString(), "Error code: " + ret.ToString()) 
        MessageBox.Show(se.Message) 
    Finally 
        If wic IsNot Nothing Then 
            wic.Undo() 
        End If 
    End Try 
End Sub 
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path you're looking for is:

```
\\157.60.113.28\D$\testnew\right.bmp
```

if you are required to interact with the remote machine regularly  it would be wise to map the network path as a network drive in your machine.

[image: mapping network drive]

Comment: Haleluia! Thank you very much.

Comment: @RobertKodra if it resolved your issue please show your gratitude by marking the V to the left of the answer.

Comment: Of course I will, it say I need to wait 3 minutes to accept the answer. Thanks you for the help and tip!